# Javascript module implementation for static sites

Tags: javascript, module

I recently starting working on porting a desktop application to mobile. I am relatively new to web programming, but my original program is a few hundred lines, so I thought I might want to use some method of organizing my Javascript instead of lumping it all into one file.

Coming from only using object-oriented languages, I liked the module pattern used with Javascript because it seems to provide a lot of the structure I am used to seeing when programming. However, I also would like to be able to have my Javascript code in separate files since I lets me be a bit more organized, and I really liked the CommonJS way of requiring dependencies. I actually learned about it through reading about Webpack. I was able to use the CommonJS require pattern and then Webpack would build my multiple files into a single Javascript file which was really convenient!

However, I recently realized (I think) that no one really uses Webpack by itself, and especially not without a backend server like Node.js. I'm not using a backend since my application doesn't require it, so I was wondering if I even really needed the overhead of a framework if my application isn't that massive.

What are some other ways that allow one to code Javascript in a OOP-like style and then concatenate all the files together? Would something like using vanilla Javascript and then combining the files with a task-runner achieve the same effect, or are there any more alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, I recently realized (I think) that no one really uses Webpack by itself, and especially not without a backend server like Node.js.

I think you're confusing a *build system* with a *backend server*. I'm sure lots of people use Webpack (and similar) to build static sites. They're using NodeJS and its ecosystem to support development and build, not (necessarily) at runtime.

In fact, the [getting started guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/get-started/) on the Webpack site gets you started with a completely static site.

> Would something like using vanilla Javascript and then combining the files with a task-runner achieve the same effect, or are there any more alternatives

That's basically what Webpack is doing. It uses the NodeJS ecosystem, but it's a build step, not a server. You can run Webpack directly, but more commonly you'd use it in combinaton with task runners like Gulp or Grunt (or, increasingly, npm's scripts feature).

Webpack isn't the old module/bundling game in town, there are several others (RequireJS, Browserify, etc.). All can be used on their own, or from task runners. None *requires* a backend server for the end result.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I wanted to thank you for this information. I searched around for build systems and found [Brunch](http://brunch.io/) to be the one best suited for what I am doing.